# Salesforce formula clarification

Tags: formula, formula-field

I need a formula for lead source on the contact record. Lead source is a picklist.

How would I make this a formula.

If lead source is empty then set lead source to web. If lead source is call-in keep it call-in. If lead source is purchased list keep it purchased list.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You want a `Workflow Rule` here, not a `Formula Field`.

Comment: IF(LeadSource = Null, Web,
 IF(LeadSource = Phone Inquiry, Phone Inquiry, NULL
  IF(LeadSource = Partner Referral, Partner Referral, NULL
  )
 )
 NULL
)

Comment: Im not sure if this is the correct way to go aobut this

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use a formula field, it will not be able to change the value of other fields, all it can do is return values based on existing fields. That means users would input data in one field, and the result of this logic would be output in a different field. If this works for your use case (reporting, etc.), you could do use a formula field:

```
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(LeadSource)), 'Web', TEXT(LeadSource))
```

---

If you want to actually have the logic make changes to the LeadSource field, the recommended method would be with a workflow rule and field update.

Workflow Rule

> **Rule Criteria**
>   Opportunity: Lead Source equals null
>   **Evaluation Criteria**
>   Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited

Field Update

> **Field to Update**
>   Opportunity: Lead Source
>   **Field Data Type**
>   Picklist
>   **New Field Value**
>   Web

---

Of course, if you are dealing with a custom field instead of the standard Opportunity LeadSource field, you also have the option of giving the picklist a default value.